# How to pass data a html file to .ts file in Ionic (latest) from a search bar input

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

The below code carries the view and .ts . I wanted to enter an input in the search bar , the input must be passed from html to .ts and the Json data which i am requesting should be filtered correctly according to the data passed.The API Url is https://api.github.com/search/users?q=dines, where the if q's value is changed , the names should be changed in the view.

## home.html

This is my view template.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>
     Git Profiles
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
<ion-item>
    <ion-searchbar floating [(ngModel)] = "myInput" (ionInput)="getNames($event) "> Search</ion-searchbar>
  </ion-item>

<ion-card *ngFor = "let post of posts?.items">

  <ion-item>
    <ion-avatar item-start>
      <img [src] = "post?.avatar_url" alt="" />
    </ion-avatar>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-card-content>
    <p>Name : {{post.login}}</p>
    <p>Score : {{post.score}}</p>
  </ion-card-content>

</ion-card>

</ion-content>
```

## home.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { PostProvider } from '../../providers/post/post';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-about',
  templateUrl: 'about.html'
})
export class AboutPage implements OnInit {

   posts:Post[];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController , private PostProvider: PostProvider ) {
  }


ngOnInit()
{
  this.PostProvider.getPosts().subscribe((posts)=> {
     this.posts = posts;
  });
}
}

interface Post{
  login:string,
  avatar_url:any,
  score:number
}
```

Comment: ts file is missing some code.

Comment: Please Can you help me with the code

Comment: Can refer link https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-select-with-searchbar/89255/21.

Comment: Could you choose the tag `ionic2`/`ionic3` please ?

Comment: It is Ionic 3. Still I am not able to figure it out

Comment: `   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

/*
  Generated class for the PostsportProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
  and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class RestApiProvider {

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello RestApiProvider Provider');
  }

  getGit() { 
    return this.http.get('https://api.github.com/search/users?q=srinivas')
    .map(res => res.json());

   
  } 
   },this is my code for providers

Comment: I wanted this link : ('api.github.com/search/users?q=srinivas') which is the api , to be used in the search where , whenever the user changes the name , "q=" should also be changed and display results accordingly. Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { PostProvider } from '../../providers/post/post';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-about',
  templateUrl: 'about.html'
})
export class AboutPage implements OnInit {

   posts:Post[];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController , private PostProvider: PostProvider ) {
  }


ngOnInit()
{
  this.PostProvider.getPosts().subscribe((posts)=> {
     this.posts = posts;
  });
}
}
search(data){
condsle.log(data);
}

interface Post{
  login:string,
  avatar_url:any,
  score:number
}
```

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>
     Git Profiles
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
<ion-item>
    <ion-searchbar floating [(ngModel)] ="myInput"  (keyup)="search(myinput)"(ionInput)="getNames($event) "> Search</ion-searchbar>
  </ion-item>

<ion-card *ngFor = "let post of posts?.items">

  <ion-item>
    <ion-avatar item-start>
      <img [src] = "post?.avatar_url" alt="" />
    </ion-avatar>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-card-content>
    <p>Name : {{post.login}}</p>
    <p>Score : {{post.score}}</p>
  </ion-card-content>

</ion-card>

</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Hello, You can try something like this*

#### home.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>
     Git Profiles
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-searchbar floating [(ngModel)] = "myInput" (ionInput)="getNames($event) "> Search</ion-searchbar>
  </ion-item>

<ion-card *ngFor = "let post of posts?.items">

  <ion-item>
    <ion-avatar item-start>
      <img [src] = "post?.avatar_url" alt="" />
    </ion-avatar>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-card-content>
    <p>Name : {{post.login}}</p>
    <p>Score : {{post.score}}</p>
  </ion-card-content>

</ion-card>

</ion-content>
```

#### home.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { PostProvider } from '../../providers/post/post';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-about',
  templateUrl: 'about.html'
})
export class AboutPage implements OnInit {

   posts:Post[];


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController , private PostProvider: PostProvider ) {

  }

    ngOnInit()
    {
      this.PostProvider.getPosts().subscribe((posts)=> {
         this.posts = posts;
      });

    }

}





interface Post{

  login:string,
  avatar_url:any,
  score:number
}
```

**ionic g pipe search**

```
 transform(items: any[], terms: string): any[] {
  if(!items) return [];
  if(!terms) return items;

  return items.filter( it => {
    return it.score == terms; // only filter country terms
  });
}
```

**Then add in `@ngModule` declarations array**

```
declarations: [
  MyApp,
  HomePage,
  SearchPipe,
],
```

#### home.html

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-searchbar floating [(ngModel)]="myInput" (ionInput)="getNames($event) "> Search</ion-searchbar>
  </ion-item>

<ion-card *ngFor = "let post of posts?.items | search : myInput">

  <ion-item>
    <ion-avatar item-start>
      <img [src] = "post?.avatar_url" alt="" />
    </ion-avatar>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-card-content>
    <p>Name : {{post.login}}</p>
    <p>Score : {{post.score}}</p>
  </ion-card-content>
```